# Как переделать пример дерева категорий с массива в объект?

Tags: php, рекурсия, объекты

Как мне под объект переделать код. Если не трудно помогите.

```
function getTree($dataset) {
    $tree = array();

    foreach ($dataset as $id => &$node) {    
        //Если нет вложений
        if (!$node['parent']){
            $tree[$id] = &$node;
        }else{ 
            //Если есть потомки то перебераем массив
            $dataset[$node['parent']]['childs'][$id] = &$node;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Я знаю точно что как то так,не знаю как с этой строчкой $dataset[$node['parent']]['childs'][$id] = &$node;

```
function getTree($data) {
    $tree = array();
    $tree=new stdClass();
    foreach ($data as $id => &$value) {    
        //Если нет вложений

        if (!$value->parent_id){
            $tree->$id = &$value;
        }else{ 
            //Если есть потомки то перебераем массив
            $data[$value->parent_id]['childs'][$id] = &$value;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пример входных и выходных данных добавьте.

Comment: Это похоже вход. А что на выход надо ?